# how to make a recursive loop for a hierarchal navigation using Php Codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, recursion, hierarchy

here is my table and I need to display it using php?

Ex. Navigation Table 
[image]

And look like this:

[image]

Is there any php code for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to write anything? If so, please share it and we'll be happy to help. You should consider using a nested tree - https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md. That will give you methods to convert your table into a hierarchy tree.

Comment: @Meezaan-ud-Din didn't ge me methods if ever can you anser it down below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in your model

```
public function getHierMenu() {
    $rows = $this->db->get('table_name')->result();

    $depthIndex = array('nav_hier_root','nav_hier_d1','nav_hier_d2','nav_hier_d3','nav_hier_d4');
    $menu = [];
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $depth = $row->nav_hier_depth;

        if($depth > 0)
        $menu[$row->$depthIndex[0]] = [];
        if($depth > 1)
        $menu[$row->$depthIndex[0]][] = $row->$depthIndex[1];
        if($depth > 2)
        $menu[$row->$depthIndex[0]][$row->$depthIndex[1]][] = $row->$depthIndex[2];
        if($depth > 3)
        $menu[$row->$depthIndex[0]][$row->$depthIndex[1]][$row->$depthIndex[2]][] = $row->$depthIndex[3];
        if($depth > 4)
        $menu[$row->$depthIndex[0]][$row->$depthIndex[1]][$row->$depthIndex[2]][$row->$depthIndex[3]][] = $row->$depthIndex[4];
    }

    return $menu;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Use this recursive function and pass the returned array (`$menu`) from the previous function to print the menu using `ul` `li`.

```
function printMenu($menu) {

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($menu as $k => $v) {
        echo '<li>';
        if (!empty($v) && is_array($v)) {
            echo $k;
            printMenu($v);
        } else {
            echo $v;
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

It's tested and working fine.

Comment: Hi thanks but I get an error ` Illegal string offset 'doggie' ` 
Found at this line : `$menu[$row->$depthIndex[0]][$row->$depthIndex[1]] = $row->$depthIndex[2];`

Comment: Please let me check, I'll update my post soon, if any mistakes found.

Comment: Alright I'm not sure why it was an illegal string offset....

Comment: Try now again with the updated code.

Comment: there is no more error but it only displays few items `Array
(
    [Animal] => Array
        (
            [0] => doggie
            [doggie] => Array
                (
                    [0] => herding
                    [herding] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => collie
                        )

                )

        )

    [Vegetable] => Array
        (
            [0] => rutabaga
        )

    [Mineral] => Array
        (
            [0] => gypsum
        )

)`

Comment: Now your array is ready with hierarchy, you just need to extract data from it and print the menu.

Comment: hmmm not sure about this one... need have that kind of output...

Comment: Beware of this code. If the order of the nav_hier_depth changes in this code, the result will be incorrect.

Comment: @Meezaan-ud-Din Thanks. But I've answered this question only and in the given scenario of the database, my code will never fail. As the depth of the database is static, the retrieving code can also be static. I know it's not a good practice to do this thing. If I did such thing I would use a parent column to maintain the hierarchy.